# In discord.py, How do I use add_roles to add multiple roles to one person?

Tags: roles, discord, discord.py

I'm coding a bot that will give a person 2 roles, one called 'Playing' and the other dependant on their current game. Right now, I can't figure out to add multiple roles at once. I'm using Minecraft as an example in this case.
Here's the related code:

```
    totestafter = str(memberafter.game)
    print(totestafter)
    totestbefore = str(memberbefore.game)
    print(totestbefore)
    playing = discord.utils.get(memberafter.server.roles, name="Playing")
    if "Minecraft" in totestafter:
      print('if2 success')
      mcrole = discord.utils.get(memberafter.server.roles, name="Minecraft")
      addroles = [mcrole, playing]
      await client.add_roles(memberafter, addroles)
    elif "Minecraft" in totestbefore:
      mcrole = discord.utils.get(memberafter.server.roles, name="Minecraft")
      await client.remove_roles(memberafter, mcrole)
      await client.remove_roles(memberafter, playing)
      print("Removal Success")
```

And here's my error:
`AttributeError: 'list' object as no attribute 'id'`

I get that it's for the list and should be an argument, but i'm still fairly new and can't figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is an excerpt of `add_role()`'s documentation:

> [***`add_roles(member, *roles)`***](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.add_roles)
>
> This function is a *coroutine*. Gives the specified `Member` a number of
>   `Role`'s. You must have the proper permissions to use this function. The
>   `Member` object is not directly modified afterwards until the
>   corresponding `WebSocket` event is received. Parameters:
>
> - `member` (`Member`) – The member to give roles to.
> - `*roles` – An argument list of `Role` s to give the member

The documentation itself is a bit misleading, since it mentions the word, `list`. In fact, the `*` means that this parameter will take [all of the leftover arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/6622817) and stores them into a list.

Therefore, your `add_roles` command needs to be changed to:

```
await client.add_roles(memberafter, mcrole, playing)
```

Or if you wanted to keep the roles in a list, just add an asterisk (`*`):

```
addroles = [mcrole, playing]
await client.add_roles(memberafter, *addroles)
```

---

Side note, like `add_roles()`, `remove_roles()` works almost the same, it *removes* role instead of *adding* them.

> [**`remove_roles(member, *roles)`**](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.remove_roles)

Meaning that you can do remove multiple roles in one command as well:

```
await client.remove_roles(memberafter, mcrole, playing)
```

---

Your full code snippet should look like this:

```
playing = discord.utils.get(memberafter.server.roles, name="Playing")
mcrole = discord.utils.get(memberafter.server.roles, name="Minecraft")

if "Minecraft" in totestafter:     
  await client.add_roles(memberafter, mcrole, playing)
elif "Minecraft" in totestbefore:
  await client.remove_roles(memberafter, mcrole, playing)
```